# How to forward define a subclass?

Tags: c++, subclass, forward-declaration

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
There are some subclasses inside one class, I want to put them into another header or cpp file.

Example in main.h:

```
class main
{
public:
    class sub
    {
        int value;
        sub()
            {value=1;}

    };

    main(void);
    ~main(void);
};
```

So far, it's fine. 
But i want to put main and sub in seperate header files.

like in newmain.h:

```
#include newsub.h
class newmain
    {
    public:
        class newsub;

    int count;
    newsub thissub;
    int count;
    newmain(void)
        {count=1;}

    ~newmain(void);
};
```

as well as in newsub.h:

```
#include"newmain.h"
class newmain::newsub
{
    public:
        int value;
        newsub()
            {value=1;}
}
```

I tired to declare newsub as virtual, but in this case the compiler tells me, it won't declare anything...?

Comment: Please show what you actually tried and the resulting error message.

Comment: A class named `main` is a recipe for trouble